# Why is (?i:abc) an unrecognized rule in flex

Tags: regex, flex-lexer

Why is the following rule not being recognized ?

```
(?i:abc) { return TOKEN; }
```

I want to return TOKEN for a case insensitive match of 'abc'.

Comment: That should as far as I can tell match unless there are conflicting rules that match first.

Comment: What version of flex? You need 2.5.34 or newer for the perlish `(?i)` to work. In standard regex syntax there's no such thing. You have to use `[Aa][Bb][Cc]`

Comment: Thanks Alan, i was using a previous version !!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check for the version of flex. We need 2.5.34 or newer for this to work. Answered by: @Alan Curry.